# Error (';' expected at line 25)

Tags: android-studio

My teacher wants us to make an app on Android Studio, so I chose to make a music app.

```
package com.example.laura.homework;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

MediaPlayer mustafa1;
MediaPlayer mustafa2;
MediaPlayer tarkan1;
MediaPlayer tarkan2;
MediaPlayer tarkan3;
MediaPlayer tarkan4;
MediaPlayer tarkan5;
MediaPlayer tarkan6;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mustafa1 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.aya_benzer_mustafa_sandal)
    mustafa2 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.melek_yuzulum_mustafa_sandal)
    tarkan1 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.simarik_tarkan)
    tarkan2 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.adimi_kalbine_yaz_tarkan)
    tarkan3 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.dudu_tarkan)
    tarkan4 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kuzu_kuzu_tarkan)
    tarkan5 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.yemin_ettim_tarkan)
    tarkan6 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.op_tarkan)
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
    }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
    return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    }
 package com.example.laura.homework;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

MediaPlayer mustafa1;
MediaPlayer mustafa2;
MediaPlayer tarkan1;
MediaPlayer tarkan2;
MediaPlayer tarkan3;
MediaPlayer tarkan4;
MediaPlayer tarkan5;
MediaPlayer tarkan6;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mustafa1 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.aya_benzer_mustafa_sandal)
    mustafa2 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.melek_yuzulum_mustafa_sandal)
    tarkan1 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.simarik_tarkan)
    tarkan2 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.adimi_kalbine_yaz_tarkan)
    tarkan3 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.dudu_tarkan)
    tarkan4 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kuzu_kuzu_tarkan)
    tarkan5 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.yemin_ettim_tarkan)
    tarkan6 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.op_tarkan)
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
    }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
    return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    }
```

and I get, in my error "stash," "';' expected (line 25)" and so on trough 32. I need help to resolve this problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you print the entire error so I can trace the call stack?

Comment: Every line has to end with a ;. Add the ; to your lines and you will get new errors (that happens a lot during coding: Fix one, get a new one :) )

Answer (score 2):

included; the end of the line 25 et seq

```
mustafa1 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.aya_benzer_mustafa_sandal);
mustafa2 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.melek_yuzulum_mustafa_sandal);
tarkan1 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.simarik_tarkan);
tarkan2 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.adimi_kalbine_yaz_tarkan);
tarkan3 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.dudu_tarkan);
tarkan4 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kuzu_kuzu_tarkan);
tarkan5 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.yemin_ettim_tarkan);
tarkan6 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.op_tarkan);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I think its b/c you didn't end any of these statements with `;`:

`mustafa1 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.aya_benzer_mustafa_sandal)
    mustafa2 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.melek_yuzulum_mustafa_sandal)
    tarkan1 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.simarik_tarkan)
    tarkan2 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.adimi_kalbine_yaz_tarkan)
    tarkan3 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.dudu_tarkan)
    tarkan4 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kuzu_kuzu_tarkan)
    tarkan5 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.yemin_ettim_tarkan)
    tarkan6 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.op_tarkan)`